# "Unfortunately <myApp> has Stopeed" after running for 45sec on Nexus4

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception

I'm a beginner in Android App Development. Using eclipse to develop a simple Bluetooth shaker app. Tried it on my phone and runs perfectly fine for about 30 seconds. And then it closes saying "Unfortunately TheApp has stopped". 
This app is supposed to switch on Bluetooth with a shake and play a beep sound(pop.mp3)

Please Help.

main.java>

```
public class BlueActivity extends Activity implements SensorListener, OnCompletionListener  {

Button a, b,d;
EditText e;
TextView f;

protected final int id=1;
BluetoothAdapter bt;

public MediaPlayer m;

private SensorManager sensorMgr;
private long lastUpdate = -1;
private float x, y, z;
private float last_x, last_y, last_z;
private static final int SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blue);

    a=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    d=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    f=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    e.setFocusable(false);



    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String s = bt.getAddress();
            e.setText(s);

        }

    });

    a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            startActivityForResult(i, id);
        }

    });

    d.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.gamerspitch.com");
            Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(in);


        }

    });

    sensorMgr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    boolean accelSupported sensorMgr.registerListener(this,SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER,
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    bt= BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if (!accelSupported) {
        // on accelerometer on this device
        sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this,SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER);
    }


}

protected void onPause() {
    m = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pop);
    m.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    if (sensorMgr != null) {
        sensorMgr.registerListener(this,SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER);

        sensorMgr = null;

        }
    if(bt.isEnabled())
        m.start();
    super.onPause();

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.blue, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(int sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (sensor == SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER) {
        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // only allow one update every 100ms.
        if ((curTime - lastUpdate)> 100) {
        long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
        lastUpdate = curTime;

        m = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pop);
        m.setOnCompletionListener(this);


        x = values[SensorManager.DATA_X];
        y = values[SensorManager.DATA_Y];
        z = values[SensorManager.DATA_Z];

        float speed=Math.abs(x+y+z - last_x - last_y - last_z)/ diffTime*10000;

        if (speed > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
            // yes, this is a shake action! Do something about it!
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Shaking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(!bt.isEnabled())
            {
                bt.enable();
                f.setText("ON");
                m.start();

            }
            else
            {
                bt.disable();
                f.setText("OFF");
            }


        }
        last_x = x;
        last_y = y;
        last_z = z;
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



}
}
```

Does it have something to do with Exception Handling? because I'm very bad at that.

Manifext.xml >

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.gamerspitch.easybluetooth"
android:anyDensity="false"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.gamerspitch.easybluetooth.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_screen" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.gamerspitch.easybluetooth.BlueActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

The logcat >

```
`08-08 16:03:33.112: E/SensorManager(4428): Exception dispatching input event.
 08-08 16:03:33.112: E/AndroidRuntime(4428): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 08-08 16:03:33.112: E/AndroidRuntime(4428): java.lang.NullPointerException
 08-08 16:03:33.112: E/AndroidRuntime(4428):    at    com.gamerspitch.easybluetooth.BlueActivity.onSensorChanged(BlueActivity.java:163)
 08-08 16:03:33.112: E/AndroidRuntime(4428):    at android.hardware.LegacySensorManager$LegacyListener.onSensorChanged(LegacySensorManager.jav a:274)
 08-08 16:03:33.112: E/AndroidRuntime(4428):    at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent(SystemSensorManager.java:371)
 08-08 16:03:33.112: E/AndroidRuntime(4428):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
 08-08 16:03:33.112: E/AndroidRuntime(4428):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
 08-08 16:03:33.112: E/AndroidRuntime(4428):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
 08-08 16:03:33.112: E/AndroidRuntime(4428):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
 08-08 16:03:33.112: E/AndroidRuntime(4428):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 08-08 16:03:33.112: E/AndroidRuntime(4428):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 08-08 16:03:33.112: E/AndroidRuntime(4428):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
 08-08 16:03:33.112: E/AndroidRuntime(4428):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
 08-08 16:03:33.112: E/AndroidRuntime(4428):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Post your logcat.. stacktrace

Comment: Yes, a stack trace would help a lot.

Comment: I have posted the error log above.

Comment: that is the mediaplayer service. which i used for every time bluetooth is turned on.

Comment: This line ...  m = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pop); ?

Comment: Try commenting that line out

Comment: I commented that line and now its Working fine.Thank guys

Comment: And could you help me out this also?
The shake is detected only on some phones like mine(Nexus4). Tried with a Sony Xperia and never recognized the shake! Please help me rectify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say what exactly is null without knowing which line is 163, but a guess would be that there has been an issue while creating the MediaPlayer object here:

```
m = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pop);
    m.setOnCompletionListener(this);
```

As the [documentation for create](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) states: a MediaPlayer object, or null if creation failed

Comment: I commented the 163 line is works fine on my nexus. But One more problem turned up is that the shake is detected only on some phones like mine. Tried with a Sony Xperia and never recognized the shake! Please help me on that

Comment: This is a different question. Feel free to ask it here on SO in order to get an adequate answer.